# Is there a scientific phenomenon allowing to repel water without using strong heat or wind?

Tags: science-based, physics, water

I want to know if there is a scientific phenomena that can repel water like some kind of water magnet, outside of using heat to evaporate it, which as far as I understand can result in violent explosion upon contact with water, or using wind to push the water away which seems tiresome.

something like this from [Moana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moana_(2016_film))

(Imgur reject the gif, just focus on the water repel from her)
https://www.cartoonsgotsaved.com/media/ocean.gif

Basically I want to use it to create a creature that biologically has a Moses/Moana ability (not necessary to have human physical or anatomy), so it is even better if this scientific phenomena can split sea for my creature to walk over, at least the limit range is not contact with any part of the creature body including hair/fur.

I know the chance is probably low but it does not hurt to ask, besides I am not knowledgeable about advance physic.

The water is not sentient, it just plain water, like earth.

feel free to edit my grammar or adding appropriate tags, since I am not sure which tag is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: on what scale, hydrophobic surfaces will work for micro-liters.

Comment: @John i want to use it to cross sea like moses or moana,  if it not clear. i dont know what scale is that. beside i did say it need to be not touching the person body though, so hydrophobic surface probably is out.

Comment: Nitpick: according to the in world explanation, Moses did not have any power. It was his manager who did it.

Comment: Since you're going for scientific accuracy (or at least plausibility,) it should be noted that even if your creature could repel water at a distance, the force excreted on it from splitting a sea would completely crush it.

Comment: Can we wait until winter season?

Comment: Do you need for the water to make a sort of canyon from the bottom to the sky, or would simply repelling water in the immediate vicinity be enough? If the latter, I think attaching some sort of bubble to itself before submerging could work. Pretty sure I have seen some insects doing it, not sure how well it can scale though.

Comment: @Alice i want splitting the sea effect like the moana one, though if the bubble physically can be as big to separate the water. i have no problem, as long the bubble is not part of the creature body like some inflated skin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As general note, a living organism which repels water might not be a living organism as we usually know it, since our concept of life is based on water.

Water is diamagnetic, therefore it is repelled by [magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation).

> A substance that is diamagnetic repels a magnetic field. All materials have diamagnetic properties, but the effect is very weak, and is usually overcome by the object's paramagnetic or ferromagnetic properties, which act in the opposite manner. Any material in which the diamagnetic component is stronger will be repelled by a magnet.

> Diamagnetic levitation can be used to levitate very light pieces of pyrolytic graphite or bismuth above a moderately strong permanent magnet. As water is predominantly diamagnetic, this technique has been used to levitate water droplets and even live animals, such as a grasshopper, frog and a mouse. However, the magnetic fields required for this are very high, typically in the range of 16 teslas, and therefore create significant problems if ferromagnetic materials are nearby. Water levitates at about 1400 $T^2/m$

If your thing can emit such a strong magnetic field, it might repel water around it.

On the other hand it will attract paramagnetic and ferromagnetic materials, and will wipe clean any magnetic recording substrate. So no credit cards. Cash only.

Comment: Might be tough to tack this onto an organism, though